# Importación de gran cantidad de registros enviados al servidor laravel se detienen

Tags: mysql, laravel, angular, importación, redis

Estoy desarrollando un servicio con angular que envía una matriz con muchos objetos a un servidor con laravel para insertar o actualizar. Cuando envío 3000 o 5000 registros, el servicio funciona normalmente, pero cuando los registros son más de 5000, sucede algo extraño.

Tengo un websocket ejecutándose con redis en el servidor para dar funcionalidad a una barra de progreso que indica el progreso de la importación de los registros. Cuando hay muchos registros, los procedimientos en el servidor se vuelven a ejecutar. Los registros que ya se han insertado o actualizado vuelven a realizar el mismo procedimiento. Esto lo sé porque en la base de datos veo la identificación incremental automática, la hora y la fecha de inserción o actualización del registro.

Sin embargo, mi primera indicación de que el proceso se estaba repitiendo era que la barra de progreso se estaba reiniciando. Como si esto ya no fuera problemático, en la segunda ejecución inesperada del proceso, la solicitud http finaliza y devuelve ERR_empty_response.

Antes de comenzar el proceso de inserción o actualización, abro una transacción y solo ejecuto una confirmación si el proceso se ejecuta con éxito. Obviamente si no ejecuta una reversión

¿Tienen alguna idea de lo que podría ser?

El entorno de tiempo de ejecución de mi servidor es nginx, Laravel 5.8 (php). La aplicación que consume el servicio está desarrollada con Angular 9

Comment: Estás enviando todos los registros en una sola petición http? Ahora si usas transacciones probablemente el problema esté ahí y no en PHP ni el servidor web.

Comment: Si, envio todos los registros en una misma petición. También ejecuto los procedimientos de insertar o actualizar dentro de una transacción. Esto es porque solo debo guardar los cambios en BD si no hubo ningún error.

Comment: Probablemente el problema raíz está justo ahí, el servidor de base de datos no logra contener todo en una sola transacción, digamos *física*. Te recomendaría que lo dividas en transacciones más pequeñas, que puedas "deshacer" si alguna no se ejecutó con éxito. Es decir el patrón saga. No la librería  (aunque ese podría servir como ejemplo), sino el patrón de transacciones parciales reversibles en caso de algún error. Un modelo auxiliar de bitácora podría servir para esto y no manejar todo en una sola petición.